# Subreport styles are ignored

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, reporting

I have a report R1 that includes a few instances of subreport R2 within a tablix. R2 highlights some rows dynamically by changing their font style:

```
=IIf(Fields!DA.Value="2","Bold","Normal")
```

If I render R2 separately everything works as expected, some rows are in normal font others are in bold. But when R1 is rendered the rows of the subreport are displayed in normal font. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2013 report designer caches report previews and do not render updates if report parameters aren't changed since previous preview.